# Docker Compose from a Bitbucket Clone Repo..Local Build Error, AppBuild Exit Code, What is it?

Tags: python, git, docker, docker-compose

It is a Python Web application from a Bitbucket Repo cloned local Windows Machine using BASH Terminal and Docker.

I can not build an application using the ( docker-compose -f build/docker-compose.yml up ) command given to me to run the app.

I receive message of an exit code error.

I need to work on the application but my Docker experience is limited and Python knowledge.

Application Structure Repo
[image]
[image]

I can get the Demos in the Docs to work on Docker and other sites but this app will not build. I have uninstalled/reinstalled. Checked drive permissions. Tried running other apps.

TERMINAL CODE

```
$ docker-compose -f build/docker-compose.yml up
Starting build_app_1 ... done
Attaching to build_app_1
app_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
build_app_1 exited with code 1

##############THE DOCKERFILE CODE
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch as base

FROM base as build

# install requirements
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# copy deps file in
COPY src/requirements.txt .

# install pip requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

FROM base

COPY --from=build /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages

# create /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy in entrypoint
COPY build/docker-entrypoint.sh .

# set env variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# start
CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

#####DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML CODE

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ./..
      dockerfile: ./build/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ../src:/app/src
```

The expected results was clone repo, run build command and go to localhost:8000 to open application.

Just keep receiving error message

```
Starting build_app_1 ... done
     Attaching to build_app_1
     app_1  | standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such 
     file or directory"
     build_app_1 exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `docker-compose` file should be at root level with rest of the files.
Then you can update it to:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: ./build/.
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
```

The build is failing because in your `Dockerfile` you have the line:

```
COPY src/requirements.txt .
```

But as you can see there is no `src` folder in the same directory as `Dockerfile`.

The folder structures seems messed up as `Dockerfile` usually is supposed to be on the same level as `src` is.